# Is (x<y)==(-x>-y) true or false?

Tags: c, gcc, system

The problem is from cs:app3e 2.82.
I learn that when `x = INT_MIN`, `-x` is also `-INT_MIN`, but

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    int x = INT_MIN, y = -3;
    printf("%d\n", (x < y) == (-x > -y));
    return 0;
}
```

on my machine(Linux version 6.2.0-34-generic (buildd@bos03-amd64-059) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38)), this gives output 1.
Why does that happen?

I use **gcc -o** to compile it.
I also use **gcc -O0** to compile it.

Comment: `-INT_MIN` is undefined behavior. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081310/why-does-int-min-int-min-and-how-the-negative-sign-operate-in-bit-level#comment125653666_71081600

Comment: This question is unclear to me. _"I learn that when `x = INT_MIN`, `-x` is also `-INT_MIN`"_ is not strictly true because of potential UB as described by others. But what were you expecting other than `1` for the result of `(x < y) == (-x > -y)`? Maybe I need coffee....

Comment: "I learn that when x = INT_MIN, -x is also -INT_MIN" --> wrong conclusion.

Comment: You could try `-fwrapv` to get the behavior you expected, or `-fsanitize=undefined` to get an explanation.

Comment: Related: [Find a value y such (x < y) == (-x > -y) will be false, when x is a signed integer and x=1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62687427) (No such value without well-defined integer wrap-around, e.g. from `-fwrapv`).  Semi-related: `-x>-y` on its own gets optimized differently by GCC for x86-64 vs. AArch64: [The Output of the C Program '(-x > -y)' Differs on macOS and Linux - Why and How to Fix It](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77339006)

Answer (score 14):

On your platform, like many others (any platform using two's-complement without trap representations, which is most modern platforms), [negating `INT_MIN` is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37307948/364696). Compilers are allowed to assume undefined behavior does not occur, and to behave however they like, including in nonsensical ways, should it occur. As a result, `gcc`'s optimizer (which still operates at a minimal level regardless of optimization settings) can exclude the case of `INT_MIN` from being a possibility when analyzing `(x<y)==(-x>-y)`, and conclude that it is tautological, substituting in `1` without performing any runtime comparisons. And in fact, [it doesn't perform any runtime comparisons](https://godbolt.org/z/qd5sdcWMP), it merely loads `1` directly for printing.

Answer (score 2):

The actual constants `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` may be a bit confusing. If we look in the C standard (C17 5.2.4.2.1) it says: `INT_MIN -32767` and `INT_MAX +32767`, meaning these are the utter minimum that must be supported, for a 16 bit `int`. For simplicity, all examples below will assume 16 bit `int` (32/64 bit two's complement systems of course use 2^31 - 1 and -2^32 so `2147483647`/`-2147483648`).

Why these values were picked is for historical reasons. In addition to industry standard *two's complement*, C also supports two exotic signedness formats: *one's complement* and *signed magnitude*. In the latter two we have a negative zero and/or trap representation, giving a possible value range of -32767 to 32767.

But the vast majority of all computers use two's complement, and then `INT_MIN` becomes -32768 on a 16 bit system. This is fine with the standard, since it just says that `INT_MIN` must be at least -32767. And in two's complement, `INT_MAX` is still 32767.

Therefore on a two's complement system, we cannot do `int x = INT_MIN; x = -x;`, since `INT_MAX` is 32767 and cannot hold the value 32768. We would create an integer overflow, which is undefined behavior - anything can happen, including strange and nonsensical code generation by the compiler.

In the upcoming C23 standard, support for exotic signedness formats will finally get removed from C. And then `INT_MIN` will likely become -32768 in the standard as well.

Answer (score 0):

> this gives output 1. Why does that happen?

As the other answers already explained, signed overflow is Undefined Behaviour in C, thus the compiler may assume that `-x` does not overflow if `x` is signed.

As your question is specifically about `gcc`: GCC supports command-line option [`-fwrapv`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fwrapv) **so that signed overflow will wrap-around** similar to like unsigned overflow does. With `-fwrapv` added to the command line options (or [`-fno-strict-overflow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fstrict-overflow) for that matter), your program will print `0` (false).

This option might disable some optimizations and enable others. It's interesting to see the effect on the slightly different program

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int x = INT_MIN, y = -3;

int main()
{
    printf ("%d\n", (x < y) == (-x > -y));
    return 0;
}
```

where the values of `x` and `y` are no more known at compile-time:

- When compiled with `-O2 -fno-wrapv`, the compiler replaces `(x < y) == (-x > -y)` by a literal `1` irrespective of the values of `x` and `y`. This is because the expression evaluates to true if no arithmetic overflow occurs, and the compiler *may assume* that it does not overflow *if* it overflows. This is consistent with Undefined Behaviour of signed overflow.
- When compiled with `-O2 -fwrapv`, the compiler cannot evaluate `(x < y) == (-x > -y)` at compile-time, and it generates code to evaluate the expression at run-time.  For the specific values supplied for `x` and `y`, the result is false.

You might also have a look at diagnostic options like [`-Wstrict-overflow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wstrict-overflow) or `-Woverflow`. And of course `-Wall`.